# Can't modify existing auto-scaling-group in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I have created a new template in Cloud Formation and I'm willing in my cloud formation template to add a new target group to an existing auto scaling group that was created manually.

What are my possibilities to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you, but at the moment, for most resources it is not possible to modify them with CloudFormation, if they are not created with CloudFormation.

While there are some notable exceptions (S3 bucket policies, EC2 security Groups), EC2 Auto Scaling Groups and EC2 launch configurations are not one of them.